# VACUUMs executed in parallel

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, vacuum

In my application *n* microservices are running on *m* nodes. Each microservice has its own database and is responsible for issuing `VACUUM ANALYZE` once in a while.

Since the scheduling of this routine job is the same for each microservice, in my naive implementation I have *m* instances of the same microservice executing the `VACUUM ANALYZE` command at the same time.

Can this pose a problem?

I guess not, because PostgreSQL will detect the parallel invocations and handle this situation gracefully. But I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

No, you could end up with many `VACUUM` processes running at the same time that way, which might be bad for overall performance.

The better solution is to let autovacuum deal with this. The parameter `autovacuum_max_workers` limits the number of autovacuum workers that can run at the same time in a single PostgreSQL cluster.

Tune autovacuum appropriately, then it should run as often and as fast as you need it to.

Comment: Autovacuum isn't an immediate solution right now, because of our access patterns that seem to prohibit successful autovacuum runs. I can fully understand, why someone would see this as a configuration problem, since autovacuum obviously is not configured to be aggressive enough.

However, nightly routine vacuums have the following benefits:
* No DB configuration necessary
 of not interfering with the usage patterns of our customers, while providing